# sparql query with special characters to dbpedia returns 400 in python

Tags: python, sparql, dbpedia

**hi every one**

**i have a query in python, which requests an sparql query to dbpedia.**

**i want to get triples with special object.**

**here is my query:**

```
query='''
            PREFIX rs: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
            PREFIX  dbo:  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
            PREFIX  dbp:  <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
            
            select distinct ?sub,?predicate
            where
            {{
            ?sub ?predicate  rs:{a1}.
            }}
            
            '''.format(a1=ent)

url = 'https://dbpedia.org/sparql/'

myobj = {"query":query, "format":"json", "default-graph-uri":"http://dbpedia.org"}

try:
     r=requests.get(url, params=myobj) 

except  Exception as ex: 

     print("error for question for entity:"+ent+" : ",ex)
```

**but the problem is when  my object has special characters, i get 400 from dbpedia.**

**here is some examples that had bad request.**

```
error for question for entity:Off_Limits_(1988_film) :  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
error for question for entity:Faith_of_My_Fathers_(film) :  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
error for question for entity:A_Rumor_of_War_(miniseries) :  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
error for question for entity:Bat*21 :  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
error for question for entity:Hearts_and_Minds_(film) :  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
error for question for entity:The_Green_Berets_(film) :  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
error for question for entity:War_in_Vietnam_(1954–59) :  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
error for question for entity:Alice's_Restaurant_(film) :  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
error for question for entity:Sir!_No_Sir! :  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
error for question for entity:Jacob's_Ladder_(film) :  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
error for question for entity:List_of_allied_military_operations_of_the_Vietnam_War_(1973–74) :  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
error for question for entity:War_in_Vietnam_(1945–46) :  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
error for question for entity:The_War_at_Home_(film) :  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
error for question for entity:Missing_in_Action_(film) :  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

```
<Response [400]>
error for question for entity:Off_Limits_(1988_film) :  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

**so how can i request to dbpedia in python correctly?**

Comment: Note that the SPARQL query appears to have a syntax error. The comma is invalid in `select distinct ?sub,?predicate` and it should be `select distinct ?sub ?predicate` instead. However, the dbpedia endpoint appears to accept the erroneous version too.

Answer (score 3):

You may also find [rdflib](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) useful for working with SPARQL queries in Python. Using it to pre-bind variables in a query can help in getting the syntax details correct and it will also help avoid potential problems with SPARQL [injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection).

Here is an example:

```
import rdflib

ent = "Off_Limits_(1988_film)"

obj = rdflib.URIRef(ent, base="http://dbpedia.org/resource/")
q = """
    SELECT DISTINCT ?sub ?pred
    WHERE {
        SERVICE <http://dbpedia.org/sparql> {
            ?sub ?pred ?obj .
        }
    }
    """
for row in rdflib.Graph().query(q, initBindings={"obj": obj}):
    print(str(row.sub), str(row.pred))
```

See also [prepared queries](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro_to_sparql.html#prepared-queries) in the rdflib documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Special characters in [prefixed names](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#prefNames) in SPARQL need to be escaped by prepending a backslash character. See [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#rPN_LOCAL) for the allowed form of SPARQL local names.

So for example instead of `rs:Off_Limits_(1988_film)` you need to use `rs:Off_Limits_\(1988_film\)` in the query.

See [this](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=PREFIX%20rs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20%20dbo%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20%20dbp%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0A%0Aselect%20distinct%20%3Fsub%20%3Fpredicate%0Awhere%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fsub%20%3Fpredicate%20%20rs%3AOff_Limits_%5C(1988_film%5C)%20.%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on) for an example query.

Comment: i solved the problem as you siad with adding this 2 lines . and it worked. thanks alot. 


`special_char=['_','~','.','-','!','$','&',"'",'(',')','*','+',',',';','=','/','?','#','@','%'] `


`ent=''.join(['\\'+c if c in special_char else c for c in ent])`